# Excel Sumproduct formula works in pieces, but not together

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Good morning StackOverflow, thank you in advance for your time.

I'm trying to use SUMPRODUCT to get a selective sum of a row of numbers.  I have column header rows that provide the selectivity.  One of those rows has a character part and a number part.  I need to split those portions and do math on the number part to selectively sum values where the number part is below a threshold.

When I F9 on each part of the formula, it works fine.  However the cell as a whole resolves to #value, because the FIND statements resolve to #value when they're left alone (they resolve fine singly and as a group when F9'd).

The SUMPRODUCT has four terms:

1: column headings of the type I want

2: nonblank cells in the discriminator row

3: those columns where the numberpart (part after a space) of the discriminator row have an earlier week number than today has (checking a lookup table to get that figure).

4: The data I want to selectively sum.

(#3 has error logic in it because I cant seem to rely on SUMPRODUCT to multiply the zeroes in #2 against #Value in #3 when the discriminator row is blank.)

Here is the code:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--($C4:$EP4="Jobs"),--($C$1:$EP$1<>""),--(NUMBERVALUE(IF(ISERR(FIND(" ",$C$1:$EP$1)),"",RIGHT($C$1:$EP$1,LEN($C$1:$EP$1)-FIND("|",SUBSTITUTE($C$1:$EP$1," ","|",LEN($C$1:$EP$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($C$1:$EP$1," ","")))))))<=INDEX(KPIs!$J$400:$R$555,MATCH(TODAY(),KPIs!$N$400:$N$555,1)-1,7)),$C6:$EP6)
```

Again, each piece (of any size- single statements up to all of #3 at once) works when F9'd, but the whole formula resolves to #value because any of the FIND statements resolve to #Value when the cell is left to resolve as a whole.

Comment: Clarification:  The entire formula works when F9'd.  But it still resolves to #Value

Comment: Are you entering this as an **array formula** or a **normal formula** ??

Comment: /facepalm.  SUMPRODUCT usually doesnt require CSE, so I didnt think of that.  Works fine now; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While you have found out a working solution, there are few aspects of your constructs that can be given more thought. Following formula shall return the same result and will not need CSE (Array) entry.

`=SUMPRODUCT(--($C$4:$EP$4="Jobs"),--(NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(" "&$C$1:$EP$1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))<=INDEX(KPIs!$P$400:$P$555,MATCH(TODAY(),KPIs!$N$400:$N$555,1)-1)),$C$6:$EP$6)`

Items to consider:

1. Part 2 `--($C$1:$EP$1<>"")` is not really giving any benefit since you are testing it out any way in part 3.
2. INDEX formula is returning reference from column P so it can be simplified.
3. Part 3 can be simplified by using a construct which you will see in many forums `NUMBERVALUE(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(" "&$C$1:$EP$1," ",REPT(" ",99)),99))` where you want rightmost part of the string.